# Simplify Query to be used as dataset in winform rdlc report

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to have this query populate a reportviewer in a winform app I am building (and will change parameters in query to values selected on form before populating report to be viewed). But the over function is not able to work. User will enter parameters from radio boxes, drop down lists etc, click search and reportviewer will open so they can print. Query is very ugly , and i have been working on it for some time. Its the only way i could get resultset in desired format.

SQL QUERY looking for help on to shorten with same results

```
DECLARE @EndReport DATETIME, @StartReport DATETIME, @Location INT, @Department varchar(50) 
SET @EndReport = '10-15-2018' SET @StartReport = '10-15-2018' SET @Department = 'fb' SET @Location = 10

SELECT row_number() over (order by (ai.FirstName + ' ' + ai.LastName)) RowNum
    ,AssociateName = isnull(upper(ai.FirstName + ' ' + ai.LastName),'**' + cast(t.ID as varchar(30)) + '**')
    ,ID = t.ID
    ,Codes = (t.DeptCode + '-' +  t.OpCode)
    ,TimeSUM = cast(SUM(datediff(second,StartTime, FinishTime) /3600.0) as decimal (6,2))
    ,Units = SUM(Units)
    ,UPH = cast(isnull(sum(Units) / nullif(sum(datediff(minute,StartTime,FinishTime))*1.0,0),0.0)*60  as decimal(10,0))
    into temptable10
FROM TimeLogNEW t LEFT JOIN AssociateInfo ai
ON t.ID = ai.ID
JOIN GoalSetUp g
ON (t.DeptCode + '-' + t.OpCode) = (g.DeptCode + '-' + g.OpCode)
WHERE EventDate between @StartReport and @EndReport 
and t.Location = @Location and g.location= @Location and  ((t.DeptCode + t.OpCode) in (g.DeptCode + g.OpCode)) and t.DeptCode = @Department
GROUP BY t.DeptCode,t.OpCode,ai.FirstName,ai.LastName, t.ID

SELECT 
 [Associate Name] = AssociateName
,[Codes] = Codes 
,[TimeSUM] = TimeSUM
,[Units] = Units
,[UPH] = UPH
,[UPH Target] = Goal
,[Actual %] = CASE WHEN goal = 0 then '0%' 
        else convert(varchar,cast(100* (isnull(UPH,0)/nullif(Goal,0)) as decimal(10,0))) + '%' END   
FROM goalsetup g join temptable10 on g.DeptCode = left(codes,2)and g.opcode = RIGHT(codes,2) 
WHERE g.Location = @Location    
ORDER BY Codes, UPH Desc
drop table temptable10
```

SQL Resultset

[image]

Visual Studio error

[image]

---

Adding visual studio screenshots. Updated after answer below

[image]

[image]

Comment: the row_number() column does not seem to be used after you generate it, just remove it from the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot know if this works, because I have no tables to test with. (i.e. If it errors you will have to decide what to do.)

- there is no obvious reason for the row_number() column, so I removed it
- `Codes = (t.DeptCode + '-' +  t.OpCode)` when making the table, followed by:
- `join temptable10 on g.DeptCode = left(codes,2)and g.opcode = RIGHT(codes,2)`
- that is inefficient, and unnecessary, just keep both columns
- in fact a lot of concatenation of dept & op codes occurs which seems unnecessary, just use the 2 columns without all that extra effort.
- `between` is a dog when used for date ranges, I strongly suggest using what I have in the query below. This date range construct of `>=` with `< (+1 day)` works for all date/time data types
- please use table aliases when referencing any column, a reader such as myself cannot know which table some of those columns come from, making it way harder to debug/maintain.

Suggested query:

```
DECLARE @EndReport datetime
      , @StartReport datetime
      , @Location int
      , @Department varchar(50)
SET @EndReport = '10-15-2018'
SET @StartReport = '10-15-2018'
SET @Department = 'fb'
SET @Location = 10

SELECT
    AssociateName = ISNULL(UPPER(ai.FirstName + ' ' + ai.LastName), '**' + CAST(t.ID AS varchar(30)) + '**')
  , ID =            t.ID
  , Codes =         (t.DeptCode + '-' + t.OpCode)
  , t.DeptCode
  , t.OpCode
  , TimeSUM =       CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, StartTime, FinishTime) / 3600.0) AS decimal(6, 2))
  , Units =         SUM(Units)
  , UPH =           CAST(ISNULL(SUM(Units) / NULLIF(SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime, FinishTime)) * 1.0, 0), 0.0) * 60 AS decimal(10, 0)) 
INTO temptable10
FROM TimeLogNEW t
LEFT JOIN AssociateInfo ai
    ON t.ID = ai.ID
JOIN GoalSetUp g
    ON t.DeptCode = g.DeptCode  AND t.OpCode = g.OpCode
WHERE EventDate >= @StartReport AND EventDate < dateadd(day,1,@EndReport)
AND t.Location = @Location
AND g.location = @Location
AND t.DeptCode = @Department
GROUP BY
    t.DeptCode
  , t.OpCode
  , ai.FirstName
  , ai.LastName
  , t.ID

SELECT
    [Associate Name] =  t10.AssociateName
  , [Codes] =           t10.Codes
  , [TimeSUM] =         t10.TimeSUM
  , [Units] =           t10.Units
  , [UPH] =             t10.UPH
  , [UPH Target] =      g.Goal
  , [Actual %] =       
                CASE
                    WHEN g.goal = 0 THEN '0%'
                    ELSE CONVERT(varchar, CAST(100 * (ISNULL(t10.UPH, 0) / NULLIF(g.Goal, 0)) AS decimal(10, 0))) + '%'
                END
FROM goalsetup g
JOIN temptable10 t10
    ON g.DeptCode = t10.DeptCode
    AND g.opcode = t10.opcode
WHERE g.Location = @Location
ORDER BY
     t10.Codes
  ,  t10.UPH DESC

DROP TABLE temptable10
```

Comment: You're right, over was completely unused, and your code worked great in sql. Now when i try to set this SP up as a dataset in Visual Studio, so i can pass WinForm parameters to it and open reportviewer with its dataset, i fail setting it up because of the temp table. Any way to get around this or get same resultset without the need for the temp table?

Comment: just remove "into temptable10" (and don't drop it once yo don't create it :-)

Comment: The second query is getting me the data i need though and is joining the temp table.

Comment: sorry. place the new first query into a "cte" `with cte as ( ... ) ` then the second query can use that name instead of the temp table e.g. `with cte as ( ... )  select * from cte join x on 1=1`  you don't have to use  the name "cte" you can name it whatever you like *even "temptable10" although that may be confusing in future*